# thymeleaf sitemesh integrate , decorate.html not parse

Tags: thymeleaf, sitemesh

in the /WEB-INF/decorate/decorate.html, i want to use some thymeleaf taglib like "th:text".

```
 <html>
 <head>
        <title><sitemesh:write property='title'/></title>
        <sitemesh:write property='head'/>
 </head>
 <body>
      <p th:text="${message}">message</p>
      <sitemesh:write property='body'/>
 </body>
 </html>
```

hello.html

```
 <html>
 <head>
        <title>test</title>
 </head>
 <body>
        Hello world     
 </body>
 </html>
```

the return result is

```
 <html>
 <head>
        <title>test</title>
 </head>
 <body>
      <p th:text="${message}">message</p>
      Hello world     
 </body>
 </html>
```

the "message" did not be parsed by thymeleaf. is it a bug?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have your template resolver and template engine configured correctly. From the HTML you are sharing you haven't defined the `th` standard dialect definition.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
        <title><sitemesh:write property='title'/></title>
        <sitemesh:write property='head'/>
 </head>
 <body>
      <p th:text="${message}">message</p>
      <sitemesh:write property='body'/>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: My configuration is correct.  Because if I put <p th:text="${message}">message</p> in hello.html, "message" 
 will be parsed correctly. Does this xmlns just use to recoginze th tags ?

Comment: If that's the case you have you view resolver looking for .jsp instead of .html